# MgTwitterEngine + SAOauthTwitterEngine generate 401 on post

Tags: ipad, twitter, http-status-code-401, mgtwitterengine

when i do a simple request using twitter api on ipad simulator, why does server send a 401 error while using iphone simulator it seems to work?

i use MGtwitterEngine and SAOauthTwitterEngine.
it looks like a common problem but i didn't find any solution throughout the web.

**SOLUTION**

control the response code in your MGtwitterenginedelegate method implementation if it's 401 you have to launch

```
[_engine clearAccessToken];
```

and relaunch login methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device needs to be authenticated separately. Did you go through the OAuth authentication process on the device?

Comment: no , do you know how to log out when i start a different simulator??

Comment: I don't think a logout is necessary. When you get a 401, however, you should automatically start your authentication process.